# Clang 7 shows external linkage for private static C++ class member on ARM

Tags: c++, arm, clang, reverse-engineering

Does it looks like a bug that Clang (versions 7 and 8 checked) builds private static member with external linkage in following case?:

```
namespace myns {
    class myclass {
    private:
        static const std::vector<string> mylist;
    ....
    };
};
```

I compile my library with --visibility=hidden to hide internal details of program. But for ARM target only (ARM64, x86 works as expected) symbol is still visible in compiled library:

> rabin2 -s *.so | grep mylist

vaddr=0x00788dfc paddr=0x00787dfc ord=084 fwd=NONE sz=12 bind=GLOBAL type=OBJECT name=myns::myclass::mylist

Why would variable name be present in binary with --visibility=hidden if it's used internally in single class?

Seems that variable name was not present in binary when I compiled with Clang 3.9 version.

Comment: This is actually unresolved LLVM bug reported here: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39413